# MongoDB:Spring data:- Embedded Array Count

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

How to identify the number of elements in the particular embedded document (or) how to find the number of elements in the embedded array?

```
Award
{
    "brand" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "multi",
            "descr" : "Multpple"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "multi",
            "descr" : "two"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "multi",
            "descr" : "three"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Test",
    "narname" : "Nar"
}
```

For Eg: In the above document how to find the number of elements that is inside the embedded array BRAND using Spring Data.?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a method which can get the answer directly.

You can use `aggregate` to implement it. For example, if you want to get the count of elements in array `brand` in a specific document, this way should be available (run on mongo shell):

```
db.Award.aggregate({$match:{_id:id}}, {$unwind:"$brand"}, {$group:{_id:"$_id", count:{$sum:1}}});
```

`count` is the result you want.

Then implement that using spring-data-mongodb syntax.

**-------------- APPENDED ---------------------**

```
// You can find the relative aggregation method from MongoTemplate.java file to handle your requirements.
// For exmaple: 
// public <O> AggregationResults<O> aggregate(Aggregation aggregation, Class<?> inputType, Class<O> outputType)
// The version is around spring-data-mongodb-1.5.0 or higher.

// Below I call the mongo-java-driver directly because I find it needs some time to learn it from spring-data-mongodb. :)

protected int getArraySize(Object id, String collName) {
    // Attention: make sure id is in the correct data type because the following statement would not convert it automatically.

    // Issue codes according to this command line:
    // db.Award.aggregate({$match:{_id:id}}, {$unwind:"$brand"}, {$group:{_id:"$_id", count:{$sum:1}}});

    DBObject match = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().push("$match").append("_id", id).get();
    DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$brand");
    DBObject group = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().push("$group").append("_id", "$_id").push("count").append("$sum", 1).get();
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.asList(match, unwind, group);

    // This aggregate method is supported in higher version of mongo-java-driver, here I use is 2.12.3
    AggregationOutput aggr = this.mongoTemplate.getCollection(collName).aggregate(pipeline);
    for (DBObject dbo : aggr.results()) {
        Object count = dbo.get("count");
        if (count instanceof Number) {
            return ((Number)count).intValue();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works from MongoDB Console. But can you suggest if we have the similar mechanism possible using Spring Data ?

Using findOne i took the document as an object to Java and then performed the list.size() to get the array count. I know its not a pretty way of doing!

Comment: @Karthik, I've appended the relative method to the result. Perhaps it will help.